# How to output the thumbnail of the featured image Wordpress?

Tags: image, wordpress, loops, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I want to output the thumbnail of the featured image of a post inside one of my widgets? How can I do that inside the loop, in Wordpress. I'm using version 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

or if you want only the image src and not all the wordpress's html output, use this:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

references:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: The thumbnail should look smth like this thumbname-150x150.jpg instead  I either get the big image shrunk with html img attributes or just the featured image.